# How to append javascript code to textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I am trying to append a textarea with some text containing a piece of javascript code. But it deletes all the tags automatically. How can I fix this problem?

Here is an example text from the database, and I stored it in `blogObject['blog_content']`:

```
<div data-configid="0/10000221" style="width: 525px; height: 292px;" class="issuuembed">     
</div><script type="text/javascript" src="//e.issuu.com/embed.js" async="true"></script>

Some text here.

<a class="fancybox" href="http://ab5b871380c75ebbed44-0d6294cd72219e531b9ba85132078296.r10.cf2.rackcdn.com/userprofiles/2012/09/19/1/images/2014/11/04/org_1415121954_3b445d4fac6b78703bcf272307ac59f0.gif"><img src="http://ab5b871380c75ebbed44-0d6294cd72219e531b9ba85132078296.r10.cf2.rackcdn.com/userprofiles/2012/09/19/1/images/2014/11/04/org_1415121954_3b445d4fac6b78703bcf272307ac59f0.gif" width="190" /></a>

Some text here 2.
```

When I use `$("#blog_content").html(blogObject['blog_content'])` to add the above text, here is what I see:

```
Some text here.
Some text here 2.
```

Comment: Use `.val()` instead of `.html()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Musa in the comment said, I should use `.val()` instead of `.html()`. It worked for me.